# LocalStorage Cleared when implementing a Remember Me and Restarting app

Tags: javascript, firebase, electron, local-storage

I am making an app with ElectronJs. I have completed the sign in page and added a remember me checkbox. I have also used the LocalStorage to implement the remember me feature, but everytime I login with the box ticked, and write rs in terminal to restart app, the LocalStorage is cleared and I go back to my sign-in page, why?

Here's my code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set, onValue, update} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-database.js";
const firebaseConfig = { ... };
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// REMEMBER ME FEATURE
const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    if (loggedIn === true) {
        window.location.href = "home.html";
    }
});

// SIGN IN FUNCTION
document.querySelector("#signInButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const code = document.querySelector("#codeEntry").value;
    const username = document.querySelector("#usernameEntry").value;
    const password = document.querySelector("#passwordEntry").value;
    const errorMessage = document.querySelector("#signInErrorMessage1")
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(), code + "/users/" + username);

    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();

        if (data !== null && data.password === password) {
            const fullname = data.name;
            const rememberMeCheckbox = document.querySelector("#cbx");

            if (rememberMeCheckbox.checked) {
                localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", true);
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", false);
            }

            localStorage.setItem("code", code);
            localStorage.setItem("username", username);
            localStorage.setItem("fullname", fullname);
            window.location.href = "home.html";
        } else {
            errorMessage.classList.add("show");
            setTimeout(() => {
                errorMessage.classList.remove("show"); 
            }, 10000); 
        }
    });
});
```